# jQuery.html() not working well with Asp.Net innerHtml

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

So basically, I have a div which is runat="server"

```
<div id="results" runat="server" class="results"></div>
```

Now, I add HTML to this using jQuery.

```
$('.results').html('Some crazy data');
```

However, when I try to access the data in this DIV using C#, it says the DIV has no contents.

```
string myResults = results.innerHtml;
```

myResults is empty.

Can someone help me out? I've never seen this behavior before.

Many Thanks!

Comment: that should work ... are you sure you're running the code when the document is ready?

Comment: That won't work as DIV doesn't get posted to server. If you want to take that data to server, copy it to a form control (say hidden input).

Comment: It is because the javascript runs client-side and the C# code runs server-side. The contents (inner html) of the div is not posted back to the server so there is no way that your C# code can access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this...

```
<div id="results" runat="server" class="results"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenResults" runat="server" class="hiddenResults" />

$('.results').html('Some crazy data');
$('.hiddenResults').val('Some crazy data');
```

Now you can access the data on server

```
string myResults = hiddenResults.Value;
```

Comment: It should be hiddenResults.Value

Answer (score 4):

This line looks like C#:

```
string myResults = results.innerHtml;
```

Presumably you're trying to access your *server*-side DIV in C#.  That happens **before** the html is sent to the browser.  Which means, that's not going to work at all since you're *setting* the value client-side in the browser (after the html has already been sent).

Comment: @Umm, yes, certainly, but it's not clear what you are trying to do.  1) Server produces HTML and sends it to the browser 2) Browser runs javascript and sets the div to contain "some crazy data" 3) You want to consume that data...when?  Where?  Why?  Please elaborate on your use case and we can recommend an approach (possibly AJAX).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mixing up jQuery and Javascript. Try

```
var myResults = $(".results").html();
```

Just to verify everything is correct, see if your `results` is defined as below

```
var results = document.getElementById("results");
var myResults = results.innerHtml;
```

---

If you trying to get the value of `results` to the server, it is not possible through jQuery or Javascript unless send an AJAX request.

Comment: However, there is no reason for your code not to work, unless `results` points to null

Comment: OP is accessing the data on the server not on the client.

Comment: @KirkWoll, LOL, Can't believe I copied that from the OP. Thanks Updated

Comment: @Starx, you modified your code but missed my point.  *The OP was using `string myResults`*.  Which means he's trying to do it on the server-side as amit_g mentioned.

Comment: @KirkWoll, I understand it now, So, fixed my answer a bit.

Comment: Yeh, I need to access it in server side, which I can't. But thanks to @amit_g, I'm able to do it in a different way.